# Mobile Site Logo Alignment

Tags: css, mobile, graphical-logo

I am looking to target my Jobspark logo while viewed on a mobile device. Currently it scrolls down the page and I would like to disable that and place it at top of the page and to the right hand side of the "Menu". This way I could delete the + symbol and it would fit nicely. Below is some code I tried to use to accomplish this. www.jobspark.ca

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
#header #logo h1.site-title {
text-align: left !important;
float: right;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
}
```

Thanks for the help.

******************Update***********************
- Logo hides behind the top navigation while in mobile
- Would like navigation color to be black while in mobile
- Menu text then needs to be white

Here is an mock up of what I would like to accomplish
[image]

Comment: give screen shots.. what now look like and how you want to place the elements..

Comment: @Dhamu Ok sorry about that, I added a image of what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

try this in **site.css**

```
#header #logo h1.site-title 
{
text-align: left !important;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Change `max-width` to 38% for `.primary-nav .nav` in **site.css**

```
max-width: 38%;
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: sorry for the confusion but I am just trying to have the above layout while viewing in mobile.

Comment: How is the UI looking after doing the above changes? I mean where is the logo coming now?

Comment: Logo appears behind the navigation now. I updated my question

Comment: I changes the answer. Please do the required changes as given in answer and this should solve your issue.